# can matrix completion work in the presence of many missing values?

Tags: missing-data, matrix

I have a matrix with about 550k elements (2500 x 220) with 100k values known and the rest are unknown.

Would it make sense to use matrix completion in this case, or are there too many values which are missing? What should I be careful of when I use matrix completion with it, if there are enough values there?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the matrix has low rank?

Comment: @Brian yes. is there a  way to decide on the rank based on the number of observed elements?

Comment: The number of observed elements isn't going to tell you anything about the rank of the matrix (you can construct examples of arbitrary rank and give the same elements of the matrix as the problem data.)  However, these low rank matrix completion problems typically exhibit a threshhold above which nuclear norm minimization will find the correct low rank matrix completion with high probability and below which your chances of getting the correct low rank completion aren't good.  This all depends on the particular class of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Low rank matrix completion algorithms may be appropriate for this problem, but a lot depends on exactly how low rank your matrix is.  Because of the size of the matrix and the number of constraints, methods that do nuclear norm minimization by solving a semidefinite programming problem with a primal-dual interior point method aren't likely to work well.  Instead, you'll want to use a method that scales better to such a large problem.

For a list of solvers, see
 [http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~srbecker/wiki/Category:Matrix_Completion_Solvers](http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~srbecker/wiki/Category%3aMatrix_Completion_Solvers)

Comment: The success of imputing the missing values also greatly depends on the nature how the "holes" were generated. If values are missing at random, there are better chances to recover the missing values in a matrix.